# texturing arrayed object without tiling

Tags: texturing, uv, modifiers, texture-painting

I built a track for my game by following a tutorial on youtube. (basically using the array and the curve modifiers) a simple texture was mapped onto a small rectangle road section which was then arrayed and mapped to a nurbs curve to produce the actual track.

Now I need to make some white lines and other race track marks on the track.
I have no idea how to do it, I tried texture painting, but once I try painting, blender suddenly freezes ( maybe because of the large no of faces), if however it didn't freeze, the same paint modification I make to some point is repeated everywhere around on the track (just as if I made the modification to the initial section and arrayed and curved it).

[image: This is what i've been working on]

Comment: have you tried aplying the array modifier? That would let you texture painting. I don't know what about the freezing, but that might not be fault of blender. I once had blender falling in certain situations and updating my graphic driver solved it.

Comment: Thanks for replyinng ak-her , yes i did apply the array modifier and that makes exact same texture and model repeated around the curve , i need to make some modification to the texture to only certain parts of the track..oh and i will check for my driver updates :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple UV maps. Add new UV map:[image]
then select your new UV map and go to UV editing layout. Unwrap your mesh and then scale all faces except those you want to have more textures down to zero and place them on the side of the UV map:[image] in this case they are those points on the sides, I gave them a little offset, so that the would be more visible. You need to make those parts, you don't want to have any further texture on some place, where the second texture is transparent. In this picture the only the not black parts are visible, so could I put them anywhere near the edge (I then used the same texture for mix shader factor with black parts for the first texture and white parts for the second texture. That's why I have there the hue/saturation and the brightness/contrast nodes. This is what my second texture looks like (maybe it's bit different, I didn't save the .blend file and I have quite a few of these pictures):[image]) When making the material, in the texture vector input plug UV coordinate your first UV map for the general texture and for each other you have to have another UV map node (please see the picture with the node tree, that should make it a bit clearer). Add new shader for each detail you want to add and mix them using mix shader and a black and white texture for factor (I generated mine right in the node tree from the texture I use for detail, just by decreasing saturation down to zero and enhancing the contrast - white parts will have the second texture added).[image]  [image] the white spot is, where the detail is (tho bottom texture is just basic wave texture and the second one is picture of a solar eclipse (above), it was first I found that could be used)
I hope this is clear enough, if not, ask in the comment.
And I almost forgot to say I am using cycles.

node tree : diffuse shader with texture as color; mixed with another diffuse shader with texture as color using the secnod texture as factor for the mix node (I'm not sure what would happen if you used colored texture, I use black and white (hue/saturation node + brightness/contrast node to decolor it). black and white defines here, where the first texture is visible and where the second (grey wold mix them together)
this is what you should see, when you open node editor with a basic textured mterial:
[image]
use wheel to zoom in, shift a to add node and use mouse to connect those together.

Comment: now I realized, that I plugged the color output of the eclipse texture in the vector input of the first texture, instead of the color input of the second. If it was correct, the white spot would be the texture of the eclipse (thus red).

Comment: Thank you soo much aky-her ... But i have a liiitle trouble following you can you please explain with a little more steps ?

Comment: I've added a little image on what i've been working on , but it has over 24000 faces :-( and unwraping it is a pain ..

Comment: I added some more details. please tell me, which parts you don't understand, so that I can improve those.

Comment: Thnak you again for helping me out aky-her .. i have a little trouble following with the node editor part , i've never been very good with that..whenever i open the node editor window, all i get is a blank screen. oh and one more thing , is there any way to export the mapped image i.e the tiled and curved image and edit it externally and remap it, so you know i can just make the marks on photoshop or something and make it not repeating.. it's just that i have a lot of random skid marks and all to put in and adding uv maps for each one of them will take forever :-(